# Linux Kernel stops initialization at random: crng init done

Tags: linux-kernel, boot, riscv

I have a cva6 design, I am not using SPI or ethernet. the OpenSBI + u-boot are working and now I am trying to port the Linux Kernel.  I use OpenOCD + GDB to boot. The DTS file is this:

```
 /dts-v1/;

/ {
    #address-cells = <0x02>;
    #size-cells = <0x02>;
    compatible = "eth,ariane-bare-dev";
    model = "eth,ariane-bare";

    chosen {
            stdout-path = "/soc/uart@10000000:115200";
    };

    cpus {
        #address-cells = <0x01>;
        #size-cells = <0x00>;
        timebase-frequency = <0x17d7840>;

        cpu@0 {
            clock-frequency = <0x2faf080>;
            device_type = "cpu";
            reg = <0x00>;
            status = "okay";
            compatible = "eth, ariane", "riscv";
            riscv,isa = "rv64imafdc";
            mmu-type = "riscv,sv39";
            tlb-split;

            interrupt-controller {
                #interrupt-cells = <0x01>;
                interrupt-controller;
                compatible = "riscv,cpu-intc";
                phandle = <0x01>;
            };
        };
    };

    memory@80000000 {
        device_type = "memory";
        reg = <0x0000 0x80000000 0x00 0x40000000>;
    };

    soc {
        #address-cells = <0x02>;
        #size-cells = <0x02>;
        compatible = "eth,ariane-bare-soc", "simple-bus";
        ranges;

        clint@2000000 {
            compatible = "riscv,clint0";
            interrupts-extended = <0x01 0x03 0x01 0x07>;
            reg = <0x00 0x2000000 0x0 0x10000>;
            reg-names = "control";
        };

        interrupt-controller@c000000 {
            compatible = "riscv,plic0";
            interrupt-controller;
            #interrupt-cells = <0x01>;
            interrupts-extended = <0x01 0x0b 0x01 0x09>;
            reg = <0x00 0xc000000 0x00 0x40000000>;
            riscv,max-priority = <0x07>;
            riscv,ndev = <0x01>;
            phandle = <0x02>;
        };

        uart@10000000 {
            compatible = "ns16750", "ns16550";
            reg = <0x00 0x10000000 0x00 0x1000>;
            clock-frequency = <0x2faf080>;
            current-speed = <0x1c200>;
            interrupt-parent = <0x02>;
            interrupts = <0x01>;
            reg-shift = <0x02>;
            reg-io-width = <0x04>;
        };


    }; 
};
```

I have placed the uImage at 0xa0000000 (0xa0000000 to 0xa098ba9e) using GDB restore command (writes a (binary) file to memory). Then I boot the OpenSBI and u-boot and it boots the image. I use the `bootm a0000000 - $(fdtcontroladdr)"` to boot the image. Also the UIMAGE_LOAD_ADDRESS and UIMAGE_ENTRY_POINT are 0x80200000. The problem is that the kernel initialization stops at `random: crng init done`

This is the output during boot

```
U-Boot 2021.07-rc4-g920075ecfa-dirty (Oct 05 2023 - 15:14:31 +0300)

CPU:   rv64imafdc
DRAM:  1 GiB
MMC:   
Loading Environment from nowhere... OK
In:    uart@10000000
Out:   uart@10000000
Err:   uart@10000000
Net:   No ethernet found.
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at a0000000 ...
   Image Name:   CV64A6Linux
   Image Type:   RISC-V Linux Kernel Image (gzip compressed)
   Data Size:    10009182 Bytes = 9.5 MiB
   Load Address: 80200000
   Entry Point:  80200000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at bffe0750
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0xbffe0750
   Uncompressing Kernel Image
   Using Device Tree in place at 00000000bffe0750, end 00000000bffe4da4

Starting kernel ...

[    0.000000] Linux version 5.10.7 (dimitriosa@carvouno3.ics.forth.gr) (riscv64-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc.br_real (Buildroot 2021.08) 10.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.36.1) #43 SMP Thu Oct 5 15:15:14 EEST 2023
[    0.000000] OF: fdt: Ignoring memory range 0x80000000 - 0x80200000
[    0.000000] efi: UEFI not found.
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   DMA32    [mem 0x0000000080200000-0x00000000bfffffff]
[    0.000000]   Normal   empty
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000080200000-0x00000000bfffffff]
[    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000080200000-0x00000000bfffffff]
[    0.000000] software IO TLB: mapped [mem 0x00000000bb1e0000-0x00000000bf1e0000] (64MB)
[    0.000000] SBI specification v0.3 detected
[    0.000000] SBI implementation ID=0x1 Version=0x9
[    0.000000] SBI v0.2 TIME extension detected
[    0.000000] SBI v0.2 IPI extension detected
[    0.000000] SBI v0.2 RFENCE extension detected
[    0.000000] SBI v0.2 HSM extension detected
[    0.000000] riscv: ISA extensions acdfim
[    0.000000] riscv: ELF capabilities acdfim
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 16 pages/cpu s25048 r8192 d32296 u65536
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 258055
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: earlyprintk
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] Sorting __ex_table...
[    0.000000] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:off, heap free:off
[    0.000000] Memory: 945184K/1046528K available (4544K kernel code, 4213K rwdata, 2048K rodata, 184K init, 328K bss, 101344K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] rcu: Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000] rcu:     RCU event tracing is enabled.
[    0.000000] rcu:     RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=8 to nr_cpu_ids=1.
[    0.000000] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 10 jiffies.
[    0.000000] rcu: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=1
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 64, nr_irqs: 64, preallocated irqs: 0
[    0.000000] riscv-intc: 64 local interrupts mapped
[    0.000000] plic: interrupt-controller@c000000: mapped 1 interrupts with 1 handlers for 2 contexts.
[    0.000000] random: get_random_bytes called from start_kernel+0x2a2/0x410 with crng_init=0
[    0.000000] riscv_timer_init_dt: Registering clocksource cpuid [0] hartid [0]
[    0.000000] clocksource: riscv_clocksource: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x5c40939b5, max_idle_ns: 440795202646 ns
[    0.000703] sched_clock: 64 bits at 25MHz, resolution 40ns, wraps every 4398046511100ns
[    0.416611] printk: console [hvc0] enabled
[    0.425853] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 50.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=250000)
[    0.446297] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.474595] Mount-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    0.490724] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    0.684930] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.723842] EFI services will not be available.
[    0.749166] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.759162] smp: Brought up 1 node, 1 CPU
[    0.807168] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.943443] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.961550] futex hash table entries: 256 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    1.018142] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    2.788080] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    2.806168] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    2.822354] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    2.949118] clocksource: Switched to clocksource riscv_clocksource
[    3.126919] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    3.187811] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 512 (order: 1, 8192 bytes, linear)
[    3.207598] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    3.232318] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    3.264580] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
[    3.302236] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    3.319141] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    3.351783] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    3.448121] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    3.460391] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    3.470736] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    3.481033] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[   29.998706] workingset: timestamp_bits=62 max_order=18 bucket_order=0
[   31.917424] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[   31.930431] Key type id_resolver registered
[   31.940197] Key type id_legacy registered
[   31.971311] nfs4filelayout_init: NFSv4 File Layout Driver Registering...
[   34.127326] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
[   34.137653] io scheduler kyber registered
[   41.220260] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing disabled
[   41.458414] 10000000.uart: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x10000000 (irq = 1, base_baud = 3125000) is a TI16750
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.10.7 (dimitriosa@carvouno3.ics.forth.gr) (riscv64-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc.br_real (Buildroot 2021.08) 10.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.36.1) #43 SMP Thu Oct 5 15:15:14 EEST 2023
[    0.000000] OF: fdt: Ignoring memory range 0x80000000 - 0x80200000
[    0.000000] efi: UEFI not found.
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   DMA32    [mem 0x0000000080200000-0x00000000bfffffff]
[    0.000000]   Normal   empty
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000080200000-0x00000000bfffffff]
[    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000080200000-0x00000000bfffffff]
[    0.000000] software IO TLB: mapped [mem 0x00000000bb1e0000-0x00000000bf1e0000] (64MB)
[    0.000000] SBI specification v0.3 detected
[    0.000000] SBI implementation ID=0x1 Version=0x9
[    0.000000] SBI v0.2 TIME extension detected
[    0.000000] SBI v0.2 IPI extension detected
[    0.000000] SBI v0.2 RFENCE extension detected
[    0.000000] SBI v0.2 HSM extension detected
[    0.000000] riscv: ISA extensions acdfim
[    0.000000] riscv: ELF capabilities acdfim
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 16 pages/cpu s25048 r8192 d32296 u65536
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 258055
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: earlyprintk
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] Sorting __ex_table...
[    0.000000] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:off, heap free:off
[    0.000000] Memory: 945184K/1046528K available (4544K kernel code, 4213K rwdata, 2048K rodata, 184K init, 328K bss, 101344K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] rcu: Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000] rcu:     RCU event tracing is enabled.
[    0.000000] rcu:     RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=8 to nr_cpu_ids=1.
[    0.000000] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 10 jiffies.
[    0.000000] rcu: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=1
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 64, nr_irqs: 64, preallocated irqs: 0
[    0.000000] riscv-intc: 64 local interrupts mapped
[    0.000000] plic: interrupt-controller@c000000: mapped 1 interrupts with 1 handlers for 2 contexts.
[    0.000000] random: get_random_bytes called from start_kernel+0x2a2/0x410 with crng_init=0
[    0.000000] riscv_timer_init_dt: Registering clocksource cpuid [0] hartid [0]
[    0.000000] clocksource: riscv_clocksource: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x5c40939b5, max_idle_ns: 440795202646 ns
[    0.000703] sched_clock: 64 bits at 25MHz, resolution 40ns, wraps every 4398046511100ns
[    0.416611] printk: console [hvc0] enabled
[    0.425853] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 50.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=250000)
[    0.446297] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.474595] Mount-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    0.490724] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    0.684930] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.723842] EFI services will not be available.
[    0.749166] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.759162] smp: Brought up 1 node, 1 CPU
[    0.807168] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.943443] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.961550] futex hash table entries: 256 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    1.018142] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    2.788080] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    2.806168] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    2.822354] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    2.949118] clocksource: Switched to clocksource riscv_clocksource
[    3.126919] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    3.187811] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 512 (order: 1, 8192 bytes, linear)
[    3.207598] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    3.232318] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    3.264580] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
[    3.302236] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    3.319141] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    3.351783] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    3.448121] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    3.460391] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    3.470736] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    3.481033] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.                                              
[   29.998706] workingset: timestamp_bits=62 max_order=18 bucket_order=0                                              
[   31.917424] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type                                                              
[   31.930431] Key type id_resolver registered                                                                        
[   31.940197] Key type id_legacy registered
[   31.971311] nfs4filelayout_init: NFSv4 File Layout Driver Registering...
[   34.127326] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
[   34.137653] io scheduler kyber registered
[   41.220260] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing disabled
[   41.458414] 10000000.uart: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x10000000 (irq = 1, base_baud = 3125000) is a TI16750
[   42.145559] printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
[   42.145559] printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
[   42.355841] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[   42.355841] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[   42.469604] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[   42.469604] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[   42.556954] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[   42.556954] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[   42.575851] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[   42.575851] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[   42.735824] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[   42.735824] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[   42.835522] Segment Routing with IPv6
[   42.835522] Segment Routing with IPv6
[   42.853287] sit: IPv6, IPv4 and MPLS over IPv4 tunneling driver
[   42.853287] sit: IPv6, IPv4 and MPLS over IPv4 tunneling driver
[   42.957518] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[   42.957518] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[   43.002516] Key type dns_resolver registered
[   43.002516] Key type dns_resolver registered
[   43.166242] Freeing unused kernel memory: 184K
[   43.166242] Freeing unused kernel memory: 184K
[   43.189748] Run /init as init process
[   43.189748] Run /init as init process
[   63.925773] random: dd: uninitialized urandom read (512 bytes read)
[   63.925773] random: dd: uninitialized urandom read (512 bytes read)
[   77.198244] random: crng init done
[   77.198244] random: crng init done
```

Why is this happening?

I tried to change the fdt_high, which was 0xffffffffffffffff but this didn't fixed anything.

Comment: The output seems to show output from 2 kernel boots. The output from the first boot finished at `[   41.458414] 10000000.uart: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x10000000 (irq = 1, base_baud = 3125000) is a TI16750`. The output from the second boot gets further, but I don't know why the entries from `[   42.145559] printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
` onwards are all output twice. Something fishy going on there.

Comment: It looks like it is running an init process `/init` though. Is that on an initrd / initramfs?

Comment: In other words, it looks like the kernel has finished its job of starting the *init* process. It is up to the *init* process to continue bringing the system up.